# PostgreSQL Spring Boot configuration in different modules

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, modular-monolith

I have divided my project into different modules: api, application, domain, and infrastructure. The main class resides in the api module, while the database configuration is in the infrastructure module. Is it possible to configure a database connection if I run the project from the api module, which is different from where the database configuration is located?

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app
    username: app_user
    password: Zaq
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    show-sql: true
```

I've set up the dependencies as follows: api -> application -> infrastructure. I encountered an error when trying this setup, so I'm wondering if it's even possible.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

However, when I moved the database configuration to the api module, everything worked fine.